# Key press event in C#

Tags: c#

I want to code a key press event to a text box to accept only alphabets.. any help appreciated.

also, the different validations that I can apply to a normal textbox to not accept anything else than alphabets. even if copy pasted  and not just key press//

thanks
reggie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a maskedtextbox control. That will solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need TextChanged event. You might also want to check MaskedTextBox control.

Comment: +1 on the MaskedTextBox... doing this any other way will get ugly, fast!

Comment: I agree with Philip.  No need to reinvent the wheel, after all.

Answer (score 0):

hook up the event on the textbox:

```
private void txtBOX_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

}
```

You can use `textchange` event, or a mask.
`keypress` as mention above is the ugliest way to do it, but the most powerfull.. you can "play" with the input data as you wish.

Comment: The thing with the keypress is it doesn't account for pasting text, draging and dropping text or voice/handwriting recognition (easy to do since Vista)...

Answer (score 0):

use these code in your key press event

```
if(!char.IsLetter(e.keyChar) && e.keyChar!=8)
{
e.handeled=true;
}
```

These will prevent your text box to accept any thing else alphabets and the backspace button.